# Some custom URI schemes not working on Edge

Tags: windows-registry, microsoft-edge, url, regedit, uri

I've discovered the concept of Custom Protocol Handlers lately and have been using it to access some desktop (.exe) applications through my browser (which is Edge).

I've registered many of my apps to the registry to be accessed through the browser, and most of them worked except for certain apps. There have been apps where you can access it through the custom URI on the first access, but you can't open it again once you've closed it. Some apps also just don't open at all even if the URI path is already registered.

Is there anything I missed or have done wrong? I would love to just open my desktop apps through Edge since most of my work just involves my browser unless I need to access these apps.

I've tried using .reg files, and the "Custom URL Protocol for Invoking Application" software to register these custom URIs to the registry. It seems to have the same effect for the apps who won't open.

One of my apps that won't open despite being registered a custom URI is DaVinci Resolve, while using the custom URI on Blizzard's Battle.net opens it at first but won't open on the subsequent clicks.